# Presenting Another View Controller Scrolls UITableView to Top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `PFQueryTableViewController`, which is set up to instantiate and present a new view controller, inside of a `UINavigationViewController`, when a row is selected.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]) { // Check our object exists
        MyNewViewController *card = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];

        UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:card];
        [nav.navigationBar configureFlatNavigationBarWithColor:[UIColor pomegranateColor]];
        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{}];
    }
    else { // Otherwise, do what we would have done.
        [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

When I select a row, the table view scrolls (not animated) all the way to the top, just before the new view controller is presented. This is the first problem, as it makes it difficult for users to keep track of where they are.

The second problem is that when I exit the new view controller, returning to the table view controller, I cannot scroll down from the first cell. It bounces, and I can see some of the second cell, but it will not go lower. Reloading the table causes scrolling to work again.

How do I keep it from scrolling back to the top, and why is it limiting the scroll after it's scrolled to the top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@implementation PFQueryTableViewController
{
    UIViewController* _rootViewController;
    UINavigationController* _nav
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]) { // Check our object exists
        MyNewViewController *card = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];

        _nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: card];
        [nav.navigationBar configureFlatNavigationBarWithColor: [UIColor pomegranateColor]];
        AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _rootViewController = appDelegate.window.rootViewController;

        [UIView transitionFromView: _rootViewController
                            toView: _nav.view
                          duration: 0.5
                           options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight |
         UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction    |
         UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                        completion: ^(BOOL finished)
         {
             appDelegate.window.rootViewController = nav;
             [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
         }];
    }
    else { // Otherwise, do what we would have done.
        [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Then from navcontroller you need call the next method for return to the table:

```
- (void) returnToTheQueryTableViewController
{
    [UIView transitionFromView: _nav.view
                        toView: _rootViewController.view
                      duration: 0.5
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight |
     UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction    |
     UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                    completion: ^(BOOL finished)
     {
         AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
         appDelegate.window.rootViewController = _rootViewController;
         [appDelegate.window makeKeyAndVisible];
     }];
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. Just for my understanding, is presentViewController the wrong way to do this?

Comment: I don't think your solution is wrong. I think you should try my solution :).

Comment: Or you can try call method [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; before presentviewController with saving current indexPath and restoring after return.

Comment: presentViewController can result in the previous view controller being deallocated. That may have something to do with the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Your solution fixed the scroll to top problem. However, even if I scroll to the selected cell programmatically, when I next try to scroll the table view, it scrolls to the top and is bounded, like before. It's almost as if the content size is being reset.

Comment: Got it. I just needed to save the contentSize and restore it when I come back.